# Toeplitz Square Peg in 3D?

Tags: geometry, 3d, curves

Can the Toeplitz Square Peg Conjecture (that all Jordan curves have an inscribed square) be extended into 3D with a cube inscribed onto some closed shape? (technical term for a closed 3D shape please?)
If so, does it have any use in relation to the original 2D problem?

Comment: For a reference, see {inscribed square problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_square_problem)